# Input field is not letting me type in an input

Tags: html, css, handlebars.js

My input field is not letting me type any text in. The only input I am able to use is previously searched terms that show up as auto-complete options.

I tried adjusting the z-index and the overflow property as several answers on this site have suggested but to no luck.

Edit: I am using Materialize CSS.

My Handlebars code:

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.login-container,
.registration-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.about-paragraph {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.gif {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.save-gif-button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#search {
  width: 50vw;
}

#about-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#about-header {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#gifs-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
}

#trending-gif,
#searched-gif {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class='teal lighten-1'>
    <div class="nav-wrapper" id="search-bar">
      <form id="search-form">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input id="search" type="search" required>
          <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>
      </form>

      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger "><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

There are no error messages that show up. I am simply unable to enter my own search terms.

Comment: your code doesn't show your trouble, are we missing something ?

Comment: Its working fine.

Comment: I see that it works here when I run the code snippet but for some reason it not working when I am on my localhost.

Comment: Where are you using Handlebars? It looks like normal HTML/CSS to me.

Comment: The file itself is a Handlebars file even though I am only writing regular HTML in it.

Comment: Which browser are you running this? try giving a height property to the input field under #search selector. Although your snippet just works fine here without that

Comment: I'm trying to run this in Google Chrome. It also did not work when I ran it in Firefox.

Comment: No luck with it working even with a height property added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the error of my code. I had placed the e.preventDefault() in my event listener before the function call which was preventing me from typing my own inputs.